# Ordering in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Saff and Snider in their book define order axioms as below:

1. If $\alpha\neq 0$ then either $\alpha>0$ or $\alpha<0$.
2. If $\alpha>0$ and $\beta>0$ then $\alpha+\beta>0$.
3. If $\alpha>0$ and $\beta>0$ then $\alpha\beta>0$.

I have to prove the impossibility of ordering in $\mathbb{C}$. So suppose $i>0$. Then using (3),  $$i^2>0\Rightarrow -1>0\Rightarrow (-1)(-1)>0\Rightarrow 1>0.$$ Now I want to show that $0>1$ as well to get a contradiction. How do I proceed?

Comment: Apply (2) and get the desired contradiction.

Comment: Actually, given your axioms, it doesn't.  But your axioms fail to prove that any exists that is greater than 0.  Most texts give the axis that if a <b then a+x < b+x for all x.  I assumed you had that as an axiom.  With your axioms, it is possible that i  < 0, 1 <0, and -1 <0.  Although it is impossible that i >0 or that -1>0 (else -1.-1=1>0 and 1+-1=0>0).  But there's nothing wrong with i, 1,and -1 all less then zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $i>0$ then $i^2=-1>0$.

Then $-1*-1 =1 >0$

Then $-1+1=0 >0$

A contradiction.

If $i <0$ then $0- i >0$ (def.  $a>b\iff a-b >0$).

Then $-i*-i  =i^2= -1>0$ and $-1*-1=1 >0$ and $-1+1=0>0$.  A contradiction.

===

First prove 1) if $x>0$ then $-x <0$ and vise versa.

Then prove 2) $x^2 > 0$ for all $x \ne 0$.

Then conclude $i^2=-1 >0$ and $1^2=1>0$ which contridicts 1).

Proof of 1) if $0 > -x \iff 0-(-x)=x >0$

Proof of 2) if $x > 0$ then $x^2= x*x>x*0=0$

If $x <0$ then $-x >0$ so $(-x)(-x)>0$ and $(-x)(-x)=x^2$.

(Of course, if you are really picky, you have to also prove $(-a)(-b)=ab $.)

Comment: In proof of (1) how does $x+(-x)>0+(-x)$ follow from $x>0$?

Comment: Actually, given your axioms, it doesn't.  But your axioms fail to prove that any exists that is greater than 0.  Most texts give the axis that if a <b then a+x < b+x for all x.  I assumed you had that as an axiom.  With your axioms, it is possible that i  < 0, 1 <0, and -1 <0.  Although it is impossible that i >0 or that -1>0 (else -1.-1=1>0 and 1+-1=0>0).  But there's nothing wrong with i, 1,and -1 all less then zero.

Comment: yes my confusion came from this second axiom.

Comment: I have *never* seen the axioms presented this way.  I think they could work but we need... more.  There's no way to compare if a >0 and b>0 then how do a and b compare?  Nor how can you determine that anything is ever positive.  The more I think of it these axioms are just not right.

Comment: It does  say on a separate paragraph that $\alpha>\beta$ if and only if $\alpha-\beta>0$. Does that help?

Comment: That helps *immensely*

Comment: So a > b => a-b > 0 => a-b+x-x > 0 => a+x > b+x for all x.  And a+x > b+x for any x => a+x-b-x >0 => a-b>0 => a>b.

Comment: So $\alpha>\beta\Leftrightarrow \alpha-\beta>0$ should be on the axioms list.

Comment: Yes, it should.  Or it should be a later definition.   $x >0$ is an abstract concept; but $x > y $ is *defined* as $x-y > 0$.

Comment: I think it's not an axiom, it's a definition of what $\alpha>\beta$ (as opposed to $\alpha>0$) signifies.

Comment: Ancientmathematician, exactly.

Comment: understood, thanks :)

Comment: So there is an abstract concept that every non zero number has some order compared to 0 so that either x>0 or x <0.  Then there are axioms given.  Then a definition for order between nonzero numbers is given.  Then a bunch of propositions can be proven via axioms.